Can't move Gazebo through Simulink in another computer
I am using ROS through two laptops. One runs Gazebo and another one should control it through Matlab Simulink. The SSH connection is successful, the Test Connection of Simulinks connects. Nonetheless when I execute my simulation Gazebo does not move, though the XY recording of the Pose says it is moving (in a total nonsense motion compared to the input though). I also tried to launch roslaunch turtlebot3_teleop turtlebot3_teleop_key.launch and the same thing happens (Gazebo does not move).
On the other side, when launching Simulink in the same computer where Gazebo is running it successfully moves it, the IP configurations are the same.





private addresses such as 192.168.1.21 do not need to be obfuscated because they are not reachable from the internet ... they only exist on your local LAN ... the same IP probably exists many thousands of times in the world on other LANs ...  besides, you missed some
